# Saiku Analytics doesn't export charts

Tags: charts, pentaho, business-intelligence, saiku

I have Pentaho BI platform 5.0 and installed latest Saiku Analytics plugin (through the Pentaho marketplace). After publishing my cube to the Pentaho Server, it's viewable from Saiku and export textual query results into various file formats (Excel, CSV, etc.), I can also *view* the charts, but exporting them (charts) is disabled (the button is not clickable) and the only way for me to export graphs is doing a printscreens which is not ideal.

Has anyone faced similar issue? Is there some additional config step to make exporting charts work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is disabled, because Paul Stoellberger disabled it in code. See [this commit](https://github.com/OSBI/saiku-ui/commit/34218c764d813a349e090d264cfc29c095852112) with description:

> disable chart export in bi5